# LINQ support in Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block

Tags: linq, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

Is LINQ support available in the Data Access Application Block.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is outdated, 5.0 version has support for linq.
The following scenarios are supported:

> - Using a DataReader to retrieve multiple rows of data
> - Using a DataSet to retrieve multiple rows of data
> - Executing a command and retrieving the output parameters
> - Executing a command and retrieving a single-value item
> - Performing multiple operations within a transaction
> - Updating a database with data contained in a DataSet object
> - Retrieving XML data from a SQL Server database
> - Querying the data returned using client-side techniques such as LINQ
> - Performing asynchronous data access with a callback handler or Lambda expression

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664416%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't include a LINQ provider, if that's what you're asking.

Suggest looking at [the list of Key Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203113.aspx) that are expedited by using the block:

> - Using a DbDataReader to Retrieve Multiple Rows. This scenario illustrates how you can use the ExecuteReader method to retrieve multiple rows of data from a database for display in tabulated form—without explicitly caching the data, using a DataSet object to manipulate it, or passing it to other components within your application. In other words, it illustrates how to display the results as quickly as possible.
> - Using a DataSet to Retrieve Multiple Rows. This scenario illustrates how you can use the ExecuteDataSet method to pass data between the components and the tiers of a multi-tier application. The data consists of one or more data tables and, optionally, the relationships that link the tables together.
> - Executing a Command and Accessing Output Parameters. This scenario illustrates how you can use the ExecuteNonQuery method to retrieve a single row that contains multiple column values.
> - Executing a Command and Accessing a Single-Item Result. This scenario illustrates how you can use the ExecuteScalar method to perform a single-item lookup.
> - Performing Multiple Updates Within a Transaction. This scenario illustrates how you can use the ExecuteNonQuery method from within a transaction to perform multiple operations against a database, where it is essential that either all operations succeed or none succeed.
> - Using a DataSet to Update a Database. This scenario illustrates how, after changing a DataSet object, you can use the UpdateDataSet method to update the database and make your changes permanent.
> - Retrieving Multiple Rows As XML. This scenario illustrates how you can use the ExecuteXmlReader method to retrieve data from a SQL Server and have that data returned in XML format.