# Using "LINQ to SQL" and "WCF Data Services" on top of Data Access Application Block

Tags: linq-to-sql, data-access-layer, wcf-data-services, daab, data-access-app-block

In my application, the entity database schema is created after application deployment based on inputs captured from end user, using a tool. I cannot use Entity Framework in this situation, since modeling is not possible without development environment (Visual Studio). The 'Code First' approach is also ruled out since it would require code generation which may lead to needless complexity.

Anyhow I need a Data Access Layer. I am therefore planning to introduce **Data Access Application Block (DAAB)** into my solution. Using **SQL Management Objects (SMO)** I can carry out the DDLs and for Data access I will use DAAB.

Now here is my confusion. Can I use **LINQ for SQL** technology on top of **DAAB**? I want **DAAB** to abstract all data access related complexities and then use **LINQ** to query. I also have a situation where I need to expose entity data through **RESTful** interface (read as **OData**). Would I be able to expose my data using **WCF Data Services** via **DAAB**?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not supported in DAAB.  DAAB is based on the good old DataSet and DataReader approach.  This post has much more detailed answer with respect to role of DAAB.

[LINQ support in Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370206/linq-support-in-enterprise-library-data-access-application-block)

I don't yet fully understand your scenario.  If your database schema is created after deployment, then hows your front end application being developed against (as there wont' be any schema, if I get your question right).

If the schema is created after deployment what functionality is in your deployed application.  Are you creating user interfaces on the fly using the dynamic schema that end user modelled?

Please do correct my understanding also good if you can give in some more info about your scenario.

Comment: Hi Rajesh. Thanks for replying. You've understood the problem right. I am working on a product. The domain entity schema is constructed after deployment. Then there are certain instruments that process the schema. The product reflects the schema to the instruments. For eg. any reporting /BI tool doesn't know what schema it will use at the time of deployment. I hope you got the picture.